# How to prove a ball is open in different metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

So, I was given, $\rho: X$ x $X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\rho(x,y)={d(x,y)\over d(x,y)+1}$.

How do I prove that for any $x \in X$ and any $\epsilon>0$, $B_{\rho}(x,\epsilon)$ is open in $(X,d)$

This is what I did: let $y\in B_{\rho}(x,\epsilon)$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\forall z, d(y,z)<\delta$. Let $\epsilon=2\delta$.

I need to show that $B_d(y,\delta)\subset B_{\rho}(x,\epsilon)$

Let $z\in B_d(y,\delta)$, then

$d(x,z)<d(x,y)+d(y,z)<2\delta=\epsilon$

I did not use the defined metric $\rho$ at all, so my guess is I did something wrong.

I would appreiate it if you can give me some idea, thank you so much.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is a fixed number. You cannot choose $\epsilon=2\delta$. For each fixed $\epsilon>0$  and each $y\in B_\rho (x,\epsilon)$, you have to find a ball $B_d( y,\delta)$ contained in $B_\rho (x,\epsilon)$

Comment: yes, i'm aware of the concept, but i'm not sure how I can do that :(

Comment: It has been shown here recently that $\rho$ and $d$ are (topologically) equivalent metrics, from which the result follows obviously. I can't find it though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$. Take $y\in B_\rho (x,\epsilon)$. We have to find $\delta>0$ such that $$B_d (y,\delta)\subset B_\rho (x,\epsilon)$$

First observe that the function $\frac{t}{1+t}$, for $t\geq 0$ is increasing. Now, note that for $z\in B_d(y,\delta)$

\begin{eqnarray}
 \rho(x,z) &\leq& \rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)      \nonumber \\
   &=& \rho(x,y)+\frac{d(y,z)}{1+d(y,z)} \nonumber \\
   &<& \rho(x,y)+\delta\\
  &&
\end{eqnarray}

From the last inequality, you can see that it is sufficient to take $\delta=\epsilon-\rho(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find it so I'll reproduce what I had said.

It suffices to show that every $\rho$-closed set is $d$-closed.
Since these are metric spaces, it suffices to work with sequences.

Let $F$ be $\rho$-closed.

Assume $x_n$ in $F$ converges to $x$ for $d$, ie $d(x_n,x)\rightarrow 0$.
Then
$$
\rho(x_n,x)=\frac{d(x_n,x)}{1+d(x_n,x)}\longrightarrow \frac{0}{1+0}=0.
$$

Since $F$ is $\rho$-closed, it follows that $x$ belongs to $F$.

So $F$ is $d$-closed.